# Cell cannot be updated (Server error)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, servlets

I am using Servlets to populate a jsp page table with mysql database data, along with jquery datatable plugin to make the tables editable.

The table edit, however, does not work and I get the error "Cell cannot be updated (Server error)" every time I edit a field and hit 'Enter'. Is my doPost method even running?

Here's my jquery scriplet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
        $(document).ready(function(){
        oTable = $("table#datatables").dataTable({
                "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
                "aaSorting":[[2, "desc"]],
                "bJQueryUI":true,
                "sDom": '<"top"i><"title">lt<"bottom"pf>'               
                }).makeEditable({
                "sUpdateURL": "/home",
                "aoColumns": [
                 null,  //medical record number
                 {},    //last name; default editing    
                 {},    //first name; default editing
                 {},    //middle name; default editing
                 {},    //date of birth; default editing
                 {      //gender, selection between M and F
                    indicator: 'Saving...',
                    tooltip: 'Click to select gender',
                    loadtext: 'loading...',
                    type: 'select',
                    onblur: 'submit',
                    data: "{'M':'M','F':'F'}"
                 }, 
                 null,  //admission date time
                 null,  //discharge date time
                 null,  //attending physician
                 {}     //room; default editing
                 ]
            });
        });
     </script>
```

And here's my doPost method of my home Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
             int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
     int columnId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("columnId")); 
     int columnPosition = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("columnPosition")); 
     int rowId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rowId")); 
     String value = request.getParameter("value"); 
     String columnName = request.getParameter("columnName");

     System.out.println(value);         
}
```

The URL mapping of my servlet is "/home"

Comment: Change this  `"sUpdateURL": "/home/UpdateData"` to this  `"sUpdateURL": "/home"` if your servlet is mapped to `/home`

Comment: Tried it, still the same error.

Comment: For debug purposes, put a log or println statement in your `doPost`. Also, your `doPost` is writing `value` to the response. Is that what you want?

Comment: That's what I wanted initially, but changed it to console writeline just to make life easier, code is updated accordingly.

Comment: inspect the AJAX request in browser console to see if it is making a connection,what data  is sent and returned(if any),and http status.

Comment: Wait, now your `doPost` isn't returning anything.

Comment: no, not at all. My XHR is empty in the browser console. And the http status for all the javascripts say "304: Not modified"

Answer (score 0):

> Is my doPost method even running?

I am not sure whehter dataTable by default makes POST request.
May be you need to add a method type POST. Something like `"sServerMethod": "POST"` or `"bServerSide": true,`

Reference :
http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/post.html

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

> "sUpdateURL": "/home"

Check you have mapped your servlet with mapping.

Easiest Way, I would suggest you to put `sys out` in both `doGet()` and `doPost()`.

Now a days with modern browsers like Mozilla Firefox you can examine Http request using tools like Firebug.

Comment: Nothing. My servlet is mapped to "home" because my doGet method, which gets all the data works fine. I implemented JQuery datatable to be able to edit the data, with doPost method on the home servlet writing to console. However, i always get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I've had had the same problem. It usually means that response doesn't end up at the servlet. Try to use just "home". Or if you have virtual name (may be you're using filter that filters all your servlets, that start with, for example with "/scheduler/") try add it before the "home". It would be look like "/scheduler/home" for example. Or try to create form with submit button (action="/home") and check if your "/home" resource is reachable.